Finding permutation of given set of decimal digits with largest number of trailing zero bits in representation
I'm trying to find a way of determining a way to represent a longish (26 character) string of digits in such a way that it contains the greatest number of consecutive trailing zero bits. The order of the digits doesn't matter, so long as it doesn't begin with a zero (needs to be a legal literal integer in Python). My initial thought was to brute force it, generating distinct permutations of the digits (with some massaging to actually generate only those permutations that don't begin with 0, and end with an even digit), but that's still a ridiculous amount of work to brute-force for that many digits.
Is there a (semi-)reliable way to narrow the search space (ideally, directly generate by some algorithm that doesn't have a broad search space) a number that contains all the necessary digits (in any order, so long as it starts with non-zero) and contains the maximum number of trailing zero bits?
For a simplified example (where a distinct permutations approach is tractable), given the digit string "011223344", the best permutation of the digits I can identify is 322310144 (binary representation 0b1_0011_0011_0110_0001_0000_0000_0000), which ends in 12 trailing zero bits (three other numbers, 144312320, 302311424, and 234113024 come close, ending in 11 trailing zero bits). I'd like to find a computationally feasible way to determine the optimal digit arrangement for something like "11122233344455566677778880" (note, not an equal number of each digit; 0 has one copy, 7 four, everything else three) or "11122233344455566688899990" or the like.
I assume it's more likely to work if the lower rank decimal digits are mostly even, but clearly that's not a reliable heuristic (e.g. in my example above, a 1 appears in the hundreds place of the best solution, while two of the slightly inferior solutions don't have an odd digit until the thousands place).

This is not an answer.
Instead, this is a long-winded comment.
This seems like a very tough nut to crack.  First of all, my (vanilla) PC handles $~10^7~$ cases ok, but starts to balk at around $~10^8~$ cases.
So, if the number of permutations exceeds (for example) $~10^9,~$ then I don't think that a home PC can handle any brute force approach.
I imagine that you will have a similar constraint against brute force, perhaps with a larger number of maximum permutations, regardless of which network of shared cpu's that you employ.

My first try, which might prove to not be feasible, would be as follows:
I would start with the (false) assumption that no permutation of any string of digits will be divisible by $~2^{21}.~$
So, for each permutation of each string of digits that you explore, you are (initially) trying to identify the largest value of $~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,20\},~$ such that the permutation is divisible by $~2^k.$
For each such value of $~k,~$ you have that $~2^k~$ divides $~10^k.~$
Therefore, for each such value of $~k,~$ there is a maximum of $~5^k~$ patterns of the rightmost $~k~$ digits that will be divisible by $~2^k.~$
So, I would pay the one time computational cost of identifying the complete list of satisfying $~k~$ trailing digits for each $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,20\}.$
So, you will end up with $~20~$ lists that can each be read sequentially, where each list has $~5^k~$ numbers, where each number has $~k~$ digits.
The next step would be to try to analyze each of the lists, perhaps by enumerating the maximum number of each of the 9's, 7's, 5's, 3's, and 1's, that occur in any entry in each such list.
The goal would be to try to analytically construct a set of rules, for a given value of $~k,~$ that the permutation can not be divisible by $~2^k~$ unless the rightmost $~k~$ digits conform to this set of rules.
Actually, having never approached anything like this before, it is unclear to me how feasible such an approach would be.  Assuming that you can construct a set of rules, for each such $~k \leq 20,~$ this would drastically reduce the corresponding computations.

Here, I am assuming that once the one-time computational cost (+ attempt at construction of analytical rules) is completed, for each value of $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,20\},~$ then you would apply these rules over and over, for each separate string of digits whose permutations you wish to explore.
The idea is that for a specific string of digits, and a specific value of $~k,~$ the application of the corresponding rules should be computationally cheap, so that you can feasibly identify whether there is any permutation of the string of digits that is divisible by $~2^{k}.~$
Presumably, for a specific string of digits, you might consider starting with $~k = 10,~$ and working downwards until you found a successful $~k.~$
If instead, $~k = 10~$ works, you might then consider working downwards from $~k = 14~$ (for example) until you identified the largest value of $~k~$ so that $~k~$ works and $~(k+1)~$ fails.
For any string of digits, if $~k < 20,~$ then you are done.  If $~k \geq 20,~$ then you should have drastically reduced the list of satisfying permutations that satisfy divisibility by $~2^{20},~$ and you can apply brute force to this list.

"I imagine that you will have a similar constraint against brute force" - Yeah, I'm running on a pretty nice Ryzen 9 workstation, but it's 32 local cores, I'm not distributing this across some massive cluster, so I can shave roughly five bits off through parallelism (it's a nearly perfectly parallelizable problem), but handling all the distinct permutations of 26 characters looks to be something that would take days at a minimum (I haven't worked out exactly how long, just that it would take well over a day), and I was hoping there might be some mathematical shortcut beyond my math background.

Manually playing around with non-distinct permutations (where the algorithm doesn't require sorting the values and relying on their natural ordering) managed to find a solution for "11122233344455566677778880" that had 38 trailing zero bits. And with distinct permutations, I've managed a solution for "11122233344455566688899990" with 35 trailing zero bits. But both were found with a lot of manual hackery, guess-and-check heuristics, and waiting 10+ minutes (hours for the 38 zero bit solution IIRC) even then.

@ShadowRanger How hard would it be to explore my idea?
